# why passing Queue and Database connection as parameter in multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I was reading `multi-threading priority queue` [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm). In this I don't understand why `workQueue` is passed as parameter
to the `self method` in class `myThread` we could have directly used `workQueue` instead of 
using `self.q`. So I wrote without it worked but then I tried to do the same for connecting to 
database.I opened a common DB connection and allowed every thread to use it. But it did not work , ( my update was not reflected in database). I thought that as threads were pre-emptying
it was not possible for them to maintain a connection to execute the query. But then I gave every thread a DB connection which I initially passed to the self method.

Basically, I implemented [this](http://themattreid.com/wordpress/2010/08/30/easy-python-threading-mysql-connections/). And to my surprise this worked. How is it different from what I was doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in this I don't understand why workQueue is passed as parameter to the self method in class 
>   myThread we could have directly used workQueue instead of using self.q

In this particular example, sure you could just reference the global `workQueue` variable. 
But that's not a very general approach, global variables might often create a mess. What if you want the object to be able to work with several different work queues for different purposes ? Better to just pass the queue you want the object to work with, instead of having the object reference a global variable.

> .I opened a common DB connection and allowed every thread to use it.

Database connections are not thread safe, so expect random stuff to happen when you do that. 
As the documentation states:

> The MySQL protocol can not handle multiple threads using the same
>   connection at once. ... The general upshot of this is: Don't share
>   connections between threads.

So what you should be doing, is use one connection per thread, which as you discovered works fine. This is different from how the `Queue` is used, which in the example code is properly locked when you access it.

Comment: @thanks alot for such detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes):

> The MySQL protocol can not handle multiple threads using the same connection at once.

That's why it doesn't works, you can't share a db connection (at least not for MySQL) between threads.

The example you linked to is creating a connection for each thread:

```
for thread in range(threads):
    try:
        connections.append(MySQLdb.connect(host=mysql_host, user=mysql_user, passwd=mysql_pass, db=mysql_db, port=mysql_port))
```

Comment: @thanks for removing my doubt cheers!!!!